# Tangent to Circle from Hyperbola Point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Tangents are drawn from any point on the hyperbola $ \frac{x^2}{9}– \frac{y^2}{4} = 1$ to the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 9$. Find the locus of mid point of the chord of contact.

I tried the following. Let the locus of mid point of contact is $hx+ky=h^2+k^2$. ( General formula)

Let $h=(x_1+x_2)/2$ &  $k=(y_1+y_2)/2$ 
Let $(x_2,y_2)$ be tangent of circle point and $(x_1,y_1)$ are point on hyperbola from which tangent is drawn to the circle. I mapped tangent as $xx_2+yy_2=9$ and putting $(x_1,y_1)$ we get $x_1x_2+y_1y_2=9$ after that I am struck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG any point on the hyperbola, $$(3\sec t,2\tan t )$$

From [this](http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-coordinate-geometry/chord-of-contact.aspx), the equation of chord of contact  $$x(3\sec t)+y(2\tan t)-9=0$$

Comparing with $$xh+yk-(h^2+k^2)=0$$

$$\dfrac{3\sec t}h=\dfrac{2\tan t}k=\dfrac9{h^2+k^2}$$

Again,
$$\dfrac{\sec t}{\dfrac h3}=\dfrac{\tan t}{\dfrac k2}=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{\sec^2t-\tan^2t}{\left(\dfrac h3\right)^2-\left(\dfrac k2\right)^2}}=\pm\dfrac6{\sqrt{4h^2-9k^2}}$$

Replace the value of $\sec t$ in
$$\dfrac{3\sec t}h=\dfrac9{h^2+k^2}$$

Then square both sides and simplify

Comment: Any point on the hyperbola is (3Sect,2tant) and not (3cost,2sint), please make modification using same step we get the answer

Comment: @Samar, I know. But I got disconnected. Will rectify soon. But I hope u have the necessary idea now

Comment: After you modify it, i will close this question

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi, Rectified. But why u want to close it?